# JQuery infinite image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row of images that are moving left or right with animate(). I am trying to make these images loop infinitely so when you click next the last image moves to the first position. Why doesn't `$(this).css("left", "-320px");` work in the if statement below.

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $("#sliderWindow").find("img").each(function(i) {
    var left = $(this).css("left");

    $("#imageContainer" + i).animate({"left": "+=220px"}, "slow");

    left = parseInt(left);
    left += 220;
    left = left + "px";

    if(left === "1220px") {
      //Why doesn't this work?
      $(this).css("left", "-320px");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I would guess that either the element's css position attribute is wrong (should be absolute or relative) or the condition `(left === "1220px")` is never met.

Comment: I put an alert into if statement and it triggers every time. #imagecontainers are absolute positioned.

Comment: Did you try $(this).css("marginLeft", "-320px"); ? I think ou should replace left attribute by marginLeft when you're using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is pretty messed up. :P But I think your statement ***is*** working, if only for an instant.

I'm going to assume that the `<img>`s returned by `find("img")` are the same as your elements with ID "imageContainerN". In which case, the problem is probably that you are setting its position while it is in the middle of an animation. It probably ends up at -320px at that moment and remains there until the next animation tween which likely happens a few milliseconds later.

You could try something more like this (the important part is swapping the order of the animation and test)...

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#sliderWindow").find("img").each(function() {
        if (this.offsetLeft >= 1220) {
            $(this).css("left", "-320px");
        }
        $(this).animate({left: "+=220px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

### Reason

Consider what happens when you set up an animation in jQuery.

1) jQuery sees you want to go +220px from current position

2) Let's say the image is currently at 100px... then jQuery says, "Okay, I'll take you from 100px to 320px over the course of, say 1 second

3) jQuery now forgets about the image's ***current*** position and just calculates where it ***should*** be to satisfy the original animation parameters on each tween

After the animation begins, you then do your if statement to reposition the element, so the following might be what happens over time...

1) Animation calculated based on parameters (current position 100px, desired position 320px)

2) After 10 millisecond, the image moves to 102.2

3) Your code executes (pretend it returned true for the current 102.2 position)

4) Your code repositions the image to -320px

5) The animation tweens again after 10ms and moves the image to 104.4px (it now appears that your image was never moved to -320px)

6) The animation tweens again and moves the image to 106.6px

7) The animation tweens again and moves the image to 108.8px

8) And so on until the image ends up at 320px

I hope that makes sense. I haven't actually looked at the jQuery animation code, but this is likely what was happening.

Comment: I can express to you in words how grateful I am :D. So I just had them backwards basically? My code looks like crap bc this is my first step into the JQuery world.

Comment: My pleasure! :D And no worries, I suck at jQuery so I can't say much. Yes, it was just backwards, and I'll update my post with (what I'm guessing is) the reason...